# Not able to update my profile (Email address already registered)

Tags: support, profile-page, login, user-accounts

Whenever I try to update my email address in the edit profile section, it says it can't update the profile because the email address is already registered and asks me to log in again above. The problem is I am already logged in when I am updating my profile.

The problem may have started when I tried to merge my two accounts, but was unsuccessful. Moreover **when I try to update my Stack Exchange profile from the Stack Overflow profile, it updates something else. My profile picture and my username are all different from Stack Overflow.**

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I don't see any usual issues related to your account that'd cause this particular "email already registered" problem, so I'm cautiously optimistic that your issue was resolved with the most recent merge.

Please contact the Stack Overflow team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page if you're still experiencing issues.